# Getting a sum of rows and retaining each row data

Tags: mysql, sql

This is what I am trying to do:

Get the sum of all rows grouping by date

Get all the rows individually

I have successfully done this... The problem is I want the order to change overall

Here is my table columns

[id][date][amount]

Example being:

1, 2013-10-01, 102.10

2, 2013-10-01, 256.15

3, ...

The output I get in Laymen's terms,

the first x of rows are the totals grouped by date

the rest of the rows are the individual amounts

The output I want in laymen's terms,

The first row is the total of the following rows by date, then rinse and repeat.

i.e.

2013-10-01, 200.00 <-- Total

2013-10-01, 150.00

2013-10-01,  50.00

2013-10-02, 300.00 <-- Total

2013-10-02, 150.00

2013-10-02, 150.00

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    t.date,
    round(sum(t.amount), 2) as total
FROM invoice t
GROUP BY t.date
UNION ALL
SELECT
    t.date,
    round(t.amount, 2)
FROM invoice t;
```

See my example at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04979/1,)!

Thanks in advance for any assistance on this.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Are you just wanting to add `Order By` to the end?

Comment: @sgeddes Sorry I didnt make that clear. I was editing my post to explain what I wanted the output to look like when you commented on this.

Comment: No worries -- was waiting to post an answer until I saw your edits.  Glad we could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean you want to change the order of your results by date (and I typically don't make such an assumption), you would simply need to add an "ORDER BY" to your sql.  The below should do the trick.

```
SELECT
    t.date,
    round(sum(t.amount), 2) as total
FROM invoice t
GROUP BY t.date
UNION ALL
SELECT
    t.date,
    round(t.amount, 2)
FROM invoice t
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: That is basically what I wanted, for some reason I didn't think that would work and I didn't try it. Thank you for the quick response. All I do now is just append , total DESC to the order by and added as total after the second select round(t.amount, 2).

Answer (score 1):

Given your edits, it appears you want to sort by date, and then total amount descending:

```
SELECT
  date,
  round(sum(amount), 2) as total
FROM invoice
GROUP BY date
UNION ALL
SELECT
  date,
  round(amount, 2)
FROM invoice
ORDER BY date, total DESC
```

- [Updated Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24ee5e/3)